# Sudo -l systemctl bypass

Tags: exploit, privilege-escalation, ctf

I am trying to privilege escalate a vulnerable box and I've stuck with this output:

```
    sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for charlie on sewers:
    env_reset, mail_badpass,
    secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin

User charlie may run the following commands on sewers:
    (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl restart webmin
```

the only other thing that I have write privileges is a script inside the webmin directory:

> miniserv.users

I've added a user that I know the credentials and I run the sudo command. Basically it adds the user to the webmin interface. But here I am stuck because in the interface I can't do anything else (all the known epxloits that I tried where not successful).

> webmin version: 1.953

Can someone pinpoint me to the right direction?

Comment: Don't just add any user — add a privileged user. What does `/etc/webmin/webmin.acl` contain?

Comment: The user that I was adding is the only one that I have known credentials. The /etc/webmin/webmin.acl file is not readable from my shell. Basically I can only add a user and run this sudo command.

Comment: I'm not familiar with webmin, but Googling suggests that you enter your own credentials in `miniserv.users`. Have you tried adding a line for `root`?

Comment: If i were in you I'll create a service named we min then you are done